# Crawling Lists of URLS from a file in batch of 2, where each batch should execute 5 Urls

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I want to crawl URLS from a file and run bunch of process in batch of 2 till all URLS are completed in the file.

Comment: What have you done till now? Post your code and ask specific problems

Comment: *"I want to crawl URLS from a file and run bunch of process in batch of 2 till all URLS are completed in the file."* So, what's stopping you from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried for the solution and got the output for it. This is what i did

```
file = open(r"d:\urls.txt", 'r')
for i in file:
    urls.append(i)

pool = Pool(processes=2)
result_list =  pool.map(crawler, urls)
```

And It worked for batch processing